# Error in Importing CSV in Magento 2

Tags: product, csv, admin-panel, magento-2.1.3

I am getting error like below while I am trying to import product as CSV in Magento 2 Admin Panel.

[image]

My Import screen is like below.

[image]

***UPDATE***

I am getting new error now.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Witch options you have selected when import file like separater , enclosed etc ...

Comment: Thanks @FeedlayTechnologies for your reply. I edited my Question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have selected field separater as pipe line(|) but in your CSV there is comma(,) so change any one

Comment: Thanks @Feedlay Technologies. How to change that ?

Comment: You have change that value in that text box

Comment: Thanks @Feedly Technologies. I am getting new error now. I edited my Question. Thanks

Comment: Becuase image are not found at /pub/media/import  derectory you have to put image there

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because it can't find the image in **pub/media/import** directory. First, upload the images to the **pub/media/import** directory and then enter in **pub/media/import** in Image File directory text field.

Comment: Thanks @Muneeb Syed. I put the images in pub/media/import directory. But I am getting the error again. Thanks